# how to make an good working select input component in vue 3

Tags: vue.js, select, vue-component, vuejs3, v-model

Im trying to make an pagination with an select field but i dont get it how the v-model and the value properties should be given, for now i have like this ↓...

**This is the select/pagination part in that component..**

```
        <p v-on:click="back" class="bg-gray-300 hover:bg-gray-400 text-gray-800 font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded-l cursor-pointer">Zurück</p>
        <p class="bg-gray-300 text-gray-800 font-bold py-2 px-4 "><span>{{siteCount}}/{{siteTotal}}</span></p>
        <select :value="modelValue" v-on:change="selectPage">
            <option v-for="select in select" :value="select">{{select}}</option>
        </select>
        <p v-on:click="next" class="bg-gray-300 hover:bg-gray-400 text-gray-800 font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded-r cursor-pointer">Weiter</p>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import SearchIcon from "../Assets/SearchIcon";
import NavBar from "./NavBar";
export default {
    name: "PaginateSeason",
    props: {
        data: {
            name: String,
            description: String,
            thumbnail: String,
        },
        siteCount: Number,
        siteTotal: Number,
        select: Array,
        modelValue: String,
    },
    components: {
        NavBar,
        SearchIcon
    },
    emits: ['next', 'back', 'selectPage'],
    methods:{
        next() {
            this.$emit('next')
        },
        back() {
            this.$emit('back')
        },
        selectPage() {
            this.$emit('selectPage')
        }
    },
}
</script>
```

**This is the main Component where i fetch anything i need...**

```
<template>
    <router-view>
        <NavBar :is-disabled="true"></NavBar>
        <div v-if="isLoading" class="flex flex-col items-center justify-center mt-9">
            <LoaderSpinner></LoaderSpinner>
            <p>Daten werden geladen...</p>
        </div>
        <div v-else>
            <PaginateSeason
                v-model="count"
                :data="seasons"
                :site-count="current"
                :site-total="siteCountTotal"
                :select="select"
                @next="paginateNext"
                @back="paginateBack"
                @selectPage="allCount"
            />
        </div>
    </router-view>
</template>

<script>
import NavBar from './NavBar'
import PaginateSeason from './PaginateSeason'
import LoaderSpinner from "../Assets/LoaderSpinner";
export default {
    name: "AllSeasons",
    components: {
        PaginateSeason,
        NavBar,
        LoaderSpinner
    },
    data(){
        return {
            seasons: null,
            current: 1,
            pageSize: 4,
            isLoading: true,
            siteCountTotal: null,
            select: [],
            count: '',
        }
    },
    mounted(){
        this.list(this.current)
        const list = async () => {
            await axios.get(`/api/seasons/all`).then(response => {
                let meta = response.data.meta
                this.siteCountTotal = meta.last_page
                for (let i = 1; i <= this.siteCountTotal; i++) {
                    this.select.push(i)
                }
            }).catch(error => {
                console.log(error)
            })
        }
        list()
    },
    methods: {
        async list(page) {
            await axios.get(`/api/seasons/all?page=${page}`).then(response => {
                this.seasons = response.data.data
            }).catch(error => {
                console.log(error)
            }).finally(() => {
                setTimeout(() => {
                    this.isLoading = false
                },1000)
            })
        },
        paginateNext () {
            if (this.seasons.length < this.pageSize) {
                this.current = 1
                this.list(this.current)
            } else {
                this.current += 1
                this.list(this.current)
            }
        },
        paginateBack () {
            if (this.current === 1) {
                this.current -= 0
            } else {
                this.current -= 1
                this.list(this.current)
            }
        },
        allCount() {
            console.log(this.count)
        }
    },
```

IF you can help me with that i would be very gratefull!

Comment: You can think of `v-model="count"` as `:modelValue="count"` + `@update:modelValue="count = $event"`

Answer (score 2):

The `count` variable on the `AllSeasons` component will not be updated, because you pass it as `v-model` to the `PaginateSeason` component, but `PaginateSeason` never emits `update:modelValue`.

Implement `selectPage` like this to address this issue:

```
selectPage(event) {
  this.$emit('update:modelValue', event.target.value)
}
```

You can also keep the `selectPage` event, or add a wach for the `count` variable in `AllSeasons` component to watch for page changes. You may also want to emit the `update:modelValue` event from `next` and `back` functions in the `PaginateSeason` component.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the reply i already tryed to make that what u told me... but there is always an warning `[Vue warn]: Component emitted event "update:modelValue" but it is neither declared in the emits option nor as an "onUpdate:modelValue" prop.` do i need to put that update event inside that select component?

Comment: @PaulThomasWeb You have an `emits` array above `methods`. You need to declare it there, like you do it with the other events. (Just add 'update:modelValue' to the array.)

Comment: okay i did it, but its still the same warning. `emits: ['next', 'back', 'selectPage', 'update: modelValue'],` i did this in the emits array. and call it in selectPage method wih event. this is the selectPage function now -> `selectPage(event) {
            this.$emit('update:modelValue', event.target.value)
        }`

Comment: It is `'update:modelValue'` and not `'update: modelValue'` (no space needed)

Comment: I'm getting this warning in vue 3 script setup  `[Vue warn]: Component emitted event "update:modelValue" but it is neither declared in the emits option nor as an "onUpdate:modelValue" prop.`. To make this warning disappear, add `defineEmits(['update:modelValue'])`. It fixed mine.